# Display issue in dialog "Google Save Smart Lock password with Smart Lock?", on Sony Ericsson WT19a (Android version 2.3.4, API 10, 320x480 pixels)

Tags: android, google-api, google-identity, google-smartlockpasswords

I'm running the code from the final branch in the GitHub repository googlecodelabs/android-smart-lock, which is associated to a Google codelab about Smart Lock ("Seamless Sign In with Smart Lock", in case you are interested).

The problem is that on my device (Sony Ericsson WT19a, Android version 2.3.4, API 10, 320x480 pixels), I get this dialog after signing in, in which the button to "Save password" doesn't appear and the message is incomplete:

[image]

It should look like this (this is the same code running on Genymotion emulator Android 5.1):

[image]

Can I do something so that the dialog displays fine on my device? Or this is an issue that only the developers at Google can address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at Google and will file a bug with the engineering team for this, but for now, you might have to disable to the save prompt on this particular device version and screen resolution :/